# dmg drag and drop an run the program

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

I have a program which create and write to a file on MAC OS X. I created a .dmg file which include my program. Now when I click the .dmg file, I can drag and drop my program to application folder. But I have to run my program in the application folder to create the file. Is it possible to make it work as when the user drag and drop to the folder, it auto run my program and when the user move my program to trash, it run my program and delete the that created earlier file?

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not. Users have to explicitly launch your app. If any app could launch itself,  we would have millions of viruses on Mac OS by now.

Comment: So is there any other way to solve my problem? I am new to MAC. I don't have to use the .dmg. Is that a way to build a installer on MAC OS X and create and delete file from the installer?